# pandas groupby and aggregate multiple values for argument 'as_index'

Tags: python, pandas

```
ctr       date        cw   mon year size teu DN#  AN#   kit vol    len W  H  QTY
abc123    6/10/2020   24   6   2020 40   2   1872 29937 y   74088  42  42 42 1
abc123    6/10/2020   24   6   2020 40   2   1872 29936 y   69184  47  46 32 1
abc123    6/10/2020   24   6   2020 40   2   1872 29932 y   92120  98  47 20 19
abc123    6/10/2020   24   6   2020 40   2   1872 29932 y   92120  98  47 20 375
abc123    6/10/2020   24   6   2020 40   2   1872 29934 y  106848  56  53 36 1
abc123    6/10/2020   24   6   2020 40   2   1872 29934 y  106848  56  53 36 142
abc123    6/10/2020   24   6   2020 40   2   1872 30994 y   76824  97  44 18 1
abc123    6/10/2020   24   6   2020 40   2   1872 30994 y   76824  97  44 18 125
```

the dataframe is a subset of 'ctr'and needs to be both grouped and aggregated on the unique AN# and keeping everything the same.For 'vol', 'len', 'W',  'H' just the max value and the 'QTY' should be summed as seen below.

**desired output:**

```
ctr       date        cw   mon year size teu DN#  AN#   kit vol    len W  H  QTY
abc123    6/10/2020   24   6   2020 40   2   1872 29937 y   74088  42  42 42 1
abc123    6/10/2020   24   6   2020 40   2   1872 29936 y   69184  47  46 32 1
abc123    6/10/2020   24   6   2020 40   2   1872 29932 y   92120  98  47 20 394
abc123    6/10/2020   24   6   2020 40   2   1872 29934 y  106848  56  53 36 143
abc123    6/10/2020   24   6   2020 40   2   1872 30994 y   76824  97  44 18 126
```

I have tried variations of the following without any luck.

````
df.groupby('AN#', as_index=False).agg({'Vol':'max',
                                                                                                             'Len':'max',
                                                                                                             'W':'max', 
                                                                                                             'H':'max', 
                                                                                                             'QTY':'sum',
                                                                                                             })```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for columns filled by maximal and sum values and then use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
c = ['vol','len','W','H']
df[c] = df.groupby('AN#')[c].transform('max')
df['QTY'] = df.groupby('AN#')['QTY'].transform('sum')
df = df.drop_duplicates('AN#')
print (df)
      ctr       date  cw  mon  year  size  teu   DN#    AN# kit     vol  len  \
0  abc123  6/10/2020  24    6  2020    40    2  1872  29937   y   74088   42   
1  abc123  6/10/2020  24    6  2020    40    2  1872  29936   y   69184   47   
2  abc123  6/10/2020  24    6  2020    40    2  1872  29932   y   92120   98   
4  abc123  6/10/2020  24    6  2020    40    2  1872  29934   y  106848   56   
6  abc123  6/10/2020  24    6  2020    40    2  1872  30994   y   76824   97   

    W   H  QTY  
0  42  42    1  
1  46  32    1  
2  47  20  394  
4  53  36  143  
6  44  18  126
```